# Error when trying to write files using 'if' function with l_ply

Tags: r, if-statement, warnings

I'm relatively new to using R in this way and I'm completely stuck with the following problem.

I'm attempting to save html pages for parliamentary debates to a local folder in order to carry out some scraping in the future.  I've written the following function (relying on other snippets of code rather than entirely freestyle!) in order to construct the directory, strip the URL down to a more understandable format (e.g. "2010-12_academieshl.html"), and then, if the file does not exist, write the file to the specified folder. (At this point I'm aware that the use of gsub below is kind of clumsy!)

```
    dlPages <- function(pageurl, folder ,handle) {
    dir.create(folder, showWarnings = FALSE)
    gsub_URL <- gsub("/stages.html", "", link_list) 
    gsub_URL <- gsub("http://services.parliament.uk/bills/", "",   gsub_URL) 
    gsub_URL <- gsub("/", "_", gsub_URL) 
    page_name <- str_c(gsub_URL, ".html") 
    if (!file.exists(str_c(folder, "/", page_name))) {
        content <- try(getURL(pageurl, curl = handle)) 
        write(content, str_c(folder, "/", page_name))
        Sys.sleep(1)
      } }
```

I'm then using l_ply to run a list (link_list) of links over the function:

```
    handle <- getCurlHandle()
    l_ply(link_list, dlPages, 
          folder = "lords_bills_all",  
          handle = handle)
```

The following error message is being returned:

```
    Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : invalid 'description' argument
```

Along with the following warning messages:

```
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In if (!file.exists(str_c(folder, "/", page_name))) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (substring(file, 1L,  :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    3: In if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong? Also, is it best to use an 'if' argument in this scenario or write a 'for' loop instead?

Thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: You need to specify what packages you're using (stringr, RCurl, plyr?). If you just want to download a vector of URLs, you can just `mapply` `download.file` in parallel across the vector and a vector of names (or derive the name from the URL and use `lapply`). Ultimately though, if you're trying to scrape you should probably just use a scraping package like rvest or XML instead so you're not saving a lot of irrelevant formatting and navigation code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Oops. The package is 'plyr'. The reason for downloading the pages is that they will have to be submitted to reviewers after I've completed the scraping. It's more convenient to send the pages that have been scraped from rather than the links which may potentially changed (or been moved) by then. I've learned this painful lesson in the past!

Is it possible with mapply to download the files and save them directly using the more understandable format?

Comment: By "understandable format" do you mean better file name? If so yes; pass a vector of URLs and a vector of paths.

Comment: That's done the trick. Thanks.